# You'll see them in future "as it is" OR "as they are"?

Tags: grammatical-number

Let all the boxes be "as they are" OR "as it is"?

Thanks for reading..

Comment: "As it is" is an idiomatic expression that can be used as it is in various contexts. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/as+it+is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:
"Let all the boxes be as they are." It's a simple matter of subject-verb agreement.
You have multiple boxes, so you need the plural form of the copula verb "be."
Hope that helps.

Comment: You are most welcome! Cheers!